# gfortran fails with a particular case of polymorphism

Tags: polymorphism, fortran, gfortran

I have a base type which contains a procedure that takes a user defined function as input. User defined functions are defined in extended types. The following compiles with ifort-13.1.3 but fails with gfortran-4.8.1:

```
module m

 implicit none

 type, abstract :: base
  contains
   procedure :: use_f
 end type base

 type, extends(base) :: extended
  contains
   procedure :: f     
   procedure :: test ! calls use_f which takes f as argument
 end type extended

contains
 subroutine f(this)
  class(extended) :: this
 end subroutine f

 subroutine use_f(this, func)
  class(base) :: this
  interface
   subroutine func(this)
    import :: base
     class(base) :: this
   end subroutine func
  end interface
 end subroutine use_f

 subroutine test(this)
  class(extended) :: this
  call this%use_f(f) ! This is the important part!
 end subroutine test
end module m

program a
end program a
```

gfortran produces

```
     call this%use_f(f)
                1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure 'func' at (1): Type/rank mismatch in argument 'this'
```

I have also tried using procedure pointers, but still ifort compiles while gfortran fails. Now, if instead of an interface block I put

```
external func
```

into use_f the code compiles successfully with both ifort and gfortran. But isn't the EXTERNAL keyword becoming obsolescent? Is there a more standard-conforming approach that works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program presented is in error.  While technically the compiler is not required to issue a diagnostic, I would expect that ifort should, though this would be a plausible extension under some circumstances.  I'd suggest reporting a bug to Intel.

As the gfortran error messages implies, the characteristics of the actual procedure argument and the dummy procedure argument are not the same.  They are required to be the same by 12.5.2.9p1 of F2008 when the interface of the dummy is explicit, bar some exceptions not relevant here.  The characteristics of a procedure include the characteristics of its arguments.  The characteristics of an dummy data argument include its type.

The type of the dummy argument in the actual procedure is `extended`, the type of the dummy argument in the dummy procedure is `base`.

What might be confusing the issue is that if you were actually calling a procedure with the interface described by `func` then it would be valid to pass an object of type `extended` as an actual argument to that procedure.  But just because type `base` is type compatible with `extended` doesn't make the types the same.

When the interface of the dummy procedure argument is implicit (say because you have used an EXTERNAL statement), then the rules around matching characteristics are relaxed.  That said, a procedure that has a polymorphic argument must have an explicit interface, so the dummy procedure argument would be impossible to use.

The external statement is not obsolescent, but it is not required if explicit interfaces are always provided (which is good practice).

Note that you have f as both a binding of `extended` and as a module procedure.  When you reference `f` as the actual procedure argument you are referring to the module procedure, not the binding.  In the code you show, there is no point having `f` as a binding.  To make sure there is no confusion - the nature of the relationship between a procedure and types that have bindings to a procedure is different in Fortran from the model used in other languages, such as C++.  Procedures are never members of a type, bindings are.  Bindings in completely different types can refer to the same procedure.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess the the above example was oversimplified because in reality 'f' needs to access some 'extended' specific variables and procedures. I don't see any other way than to have 'f' as a binding. Also, I'm not sure I understand "a procedure that has a polymorphic argument must have an explicit interface, so the dummy procedure argument would be impossible to use". With the EXTERNAL keyword, 'f' is used by calling f(this, <arg>) in the subroutine, which seems to work as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the example was simplified. I meant to say 'f' is used by calling f(this) in the subroutine.

Comment: I think you are confusing bindings and procedures.  Your example code doesn't reference the binding `f` at all.  Two possibilities - use_f takes a procedure as an argument, which gives callers flexibility in the procedure that is passed in.   Instead of an argument, should that in fact be a deferred binding of the base type that extensions are required to implement?  If not, then the argument in the procedure `f` should be class(base), and you could use SELECT TYPE to make the argument available as an object of type extended (assuming that the actual argument was of that type).

Comment: In your question, you said that you applied EXTERNAL to the func thing, that happens to be a dummy procedure.  func would then be the thing that had no explicit interface.  If the procedure that is associated with that dummy procedure has a polymorphic argument, then you cannot reference func.

Comment: And I've decided that this is not a plausible extension.

Comment: I can't use the deferred binding because not all extended types have a procedure with an 'f' interface, i.e. only some can call 'use_f'. Also, I'm still scratching my head over your polymorphic argument comment. Lets say the contents of 'f' were print*,'test' and in 'use_f' there was somewhere a call to f(this). Then the program would print "test" or do whatever is put into 'f' (in practice I'm calling f(this, arg), where 'arg' is determined in 'use_f').

Comment: But anyway, I rewrote the code such that all 'extended' specific variables are passed as an extra argument to 'f', which is not type-bound anymore. Not sure why it seemed like a bad idea at first (I'm more used to C++ and was stuck with an OOP approach.)